# Saving data in excel shared workbook

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, saving-data, vba

I made an amateur winform, which saves data from textboxes to a shared excel workbook in a first blank row of a specified worksheet. This winform is present on 3 PC's and the workbook is reachable on dropbox. In my situation I cannot make a shared folder instead of dropbox, because the network is a huge one + password protected and I won't get to know it, so the only "shared folder" alternatives are stuff like Dropbox.

Sometimes users need to open the workbook and write&save some data manually. This case gives additional "conflicted copy" files (because dropbox is incompatible of merging information of 2 simultaneously altered files).

If i could somehow make the excel file to be available to only one user at a time - this would make the winform crash on buttonclick if the workbook is open on any other PC.

The excellent goal would be enabling changes the workbook both by the winform and manual input and not getting any conflicting changes choices by excel and conflicted copy files on dropbox.

Any ideas? Thx in advance!

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/is-it-possible-to-know-if-a-file-is-currently-opened-by-someone-else-in-dropbox

Comment: You could rig up VBA to record opening & closing the workbook, on a hidden worksheet based on the user name using something like (Environ$("Username")). But it could be a nightmare if things get out of sync, such as if Excel crashes, which is common.

Answer (score -1):

In all honesty, i think you would be better off making your users use a shared google docs spreadsheet, that they can all alter at the same time. You can use many different sheets to prevent confusion or data corruption.

Or if you really need to use a winform, save the data to ( and load from ) a sql express DB, which was made for small multiuser applications. Winforms can link to MS sql express really easily.